# Нужна помощь с select

Tags: html

А как сделать через select(у меня их два), чтобы при нажатии на кнопку, основываясь на данных, которые я выбрал меня перекидывала на соответствующую страницу

```
<div class="block3"><p>Выберите ваш институт</p></div>
            <form action="#" method="post">
                <div class="select">
                    <select name="selection" >
                        <option value="">Не выбрано</option>
                        <option value="">Первый институт</option>
                    </select>
                </div>


                <img src="../img/41.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="block4"><p>Выберите вашу группу</p></div>
                <div class="select2">
                    <select name="selection2" >
                        <option value="">Не выбрано</option>
                        <option value="">Первая группа</option>
                    </select>
                </div>


                <input type="submit" name="button" value="Отправить">


        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы можете подключить небольшой js скрипт, и прописать в нем условия перехода на нужные страницы.

```
<body>
    <div>
        <form>
            <select id="selectOne">
                <option value="Не выбрано">Не выбрано</option>
                <option value="Первый институт">Первый институт</option>
            </select>
            <input type="button" value="Go" onClick="redirect()">
        </form>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        function redirect() {
            let condition = document.getElementById('selectOne').value;
            if (condition === 'Первый институт')
                window.location.href = 'https://google.com';
            else
                alert('Не выбран институт');
        }
    </script>
</body>
```